# No puedo hacer que un video embebido de youtube se vea en una ventana popup

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

Resulta que estoy haciendo una ventana emergente solo con *HTML* que contiene un *iframe* de un video de Youtube, que no tiene ninguna restricción de contenido ni de inserción, pero al abrir esta ventana el video me dice que no se puede reproducir.

El código de mi *HTML* es el siguiente:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sin título</title>
    </head>

    <body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden;font-family: arial;  font-size: 12px;">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rIc8SPMrbvs?autoplay=1&amp;fs=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;cc_load_policy=0&amp;start=&amp;end=&amp;controls=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" height="100%" width="100%">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

El video, esta público, permite ser embebido, no tiene restricciones de ningún tipo.

No entiendo porque no lo puedo reproducir en esta ventana emergente.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Tengo una app en electrónica que hace usar de iframws y 0redente el mismo problema, parece que se oye de deber a tu conexión o simplemente fallos con YouTube, pues en mi casi espero un momento volví a intentar y funcionó

Comment: Es un problema de Youtube, prueba con otros videos y verás que tu código es correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos he reescrito el proceso con un modal en html y css y funciona bien

```
<div id="modalVideo" class="modalDialog">
                        <div>
                            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                            <h3>Mi video</h3>
                             <div>
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rIc8SPMrbvs" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

para implementarlo puedes utilizar este css y adaptarlo

```
/* para Modal */
 .modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* funcionalidad al modal*/
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    margin-left:6
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 600px;
    
    position: relative;
    margin-left:6%;
    margin-top:16%;
    //margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #ddd);
}
/* cerrando el modal */
.close {
    background: #f02d00;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```